How to "Accept All" cookies with Webdriver and selenium on Kayak flight search?
Attempting to parse flights data using Selenium WebDriver. Kayak gives a cookie popup straight away:

I want to click the "Accept all" button.
HTML
<button role="button" class="RxNS RxNS-mod-stretch RxNS-mod-variant-outline RxNS-mod-theme-base RxNS-mod-shape-default RxNS-mod-spacing-base RxNS-mod-size-small" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
  <div class="RxNS-button-container">
    <div class="RxNS-button-content">Accept all</div>
  </div>
</button>
<div class="RxNS-button-container">
  <div class="RxNS-button-content">Accept all</div>
</div>

Code
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("_tt_enable_cookie=1")
url = "https://www.kayak.co.uk/flights/LON-MXP/2024-06-14/2024-06-16?fs=takeoff=1724,2200__1628,2200;stops=~0&sort=bestflight_a"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Admin\Local Documents\Python\flights2\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#RxNS RxNS-mod-stretch RxNS-mod-variant-outline RxNS-mod-theme-base RxNS-mod-shape-default RxNS-mod-spacing-base RxNS-mod-size-small > div"))).click()

There is no button id or other identifiers to click it. Anything I try returns "TimeoutException"
Thanks in advance.

That xpath matches the first div following the button, but I think you actually wanted the second inner div...

Thanks! Just tried "     WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#RxNS-button-content > div"))).click() " and got same error.

Hmm.  div elements generally aren't clickable, so maybe that is the problem.  Maybe try clicking just the button element?

The problem is I don't know how to identify it, there is no id...?

I don't know how to identify it What?  Yes you do.  The xpath in the post already identifies that element, followed by > div.  Just remove > div at the end.

Unless you mean to say that there is more than one button element with that exact set of classes?

I tried "button#RxNS RxNS-mod-stretch RxNS-mod-variant-outline RxNS-mod-theme-base RxNS-mod-shape-default RxNS-mod-spacing-base RxNS-mod-size-small", sadly same error.
But yes, all three options have the same class.

The easiest way to find that link is to use the XPath below,
//div[text()='Accept all']


Some feedback,

According to the docs

Warning: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits.

In other words, don't use .implicitly_wait() and WebDriverWait together.

According to the Selenium lead and contributors, you should not use implicit waits. Instead use WebDriverWait as needed.

As of Selenium 4.6, SeleniumManager was added and it automatically takes care of downloading and configuring the appropriate driver for you. So, you no longer need to use a DriverManager or specify the path, etc.

You weren't actually passing in your chrome_options to the Chrome instantiation.


Taking all of this into account, your updated code looks like
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("_tt_enable_cookie=1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()

url = "https://www.kayak.co.uk/flights/LON-MXP/2024-06-14/2024-06-16?fs=takeoff=1724,2200__1628,2200;stops=~0&sort=bestflight_a"
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Accept all']"))).click()


Firstly, "//div[text()='Accept all']" worked like a charm! Thank you very much for this!
Secondly, all points regarding the rest of the code noted, much appreciated the advice!

You can use the if and else method together with xpath, so if cookies are not encountered, the application continues without any problems
maybe or you can try it
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--accept-all-cookies")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


Thank you. I tried it, but the same result. I think that's due to message coming up a few moments after the page is loaded?

I usually use date.time when I use a spider form or when doing scrapy, or sometimes I try to pull data via JS. In such cases, it sometimes works. Sometimes I make it select cookies manually by using xpath and using date.time, but then it is necessary to develop a special script for each platform. :)))
